# Testing and reporting Invoke-command execution

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have the following `PowerShell` script that creates a session with Windows server administrator account.I want to report in case of failure of `Invoke-command` the error and save it in a file 
Below is the code that I wrote but if i tamper for example `.json` file(set a wrong username),execution fails and `error_report.txt` is not created

```
#Param(
$user = "lamda"
#)
$user_domain = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain
$user_computer = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
$file = "error_report.txt"
If ((Test-Path "creds.json") -eq $True) 
{
$jsonfile = Get-ChildItem creds.json 

if ($jsonfile.Length -eq 0) 
{
   #$file = "error_report.txt"
   Set-Content -Path $file -Value "Error:The file 'creds.json' is empty"
   break

}
else
{
   $creds= (Get-Content creds.json | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json)
   $admin = $creds.username
   $passwd = $creds.password
   if (($admin) -and ($passwd))
   { 
     $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwd -AsPlainText -Force
     $credential = [pscredential]::new($admin,$Password)
     $command = Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server.$user_domain -FilePath 
     C:\SECnology\Data\Utilities\Updating.ps1 -ArgumentList 
     $user,$admin,$user_computer -Credential $credential 
     If ($command -eq $false)
     { 
      $file = "error_report.txt"
      Set-Content -Path $file -Value "Error:Session between user and server 
      could not be created,please check your Credentials"
     }
     break

   }
   elseif (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($admin)) -or ([string 
   ]::IsNullOrEmpty($passwd))) 
   {
      #$file = "error_report.txt"
      Set-Content -Path $file -Value "Error:One object of 'creds.json' seems 
      to be empty.Please check your file "
   }
}
break
}
else 
{
#$file = "error_report.txt"
Set-Content -Path $file -Value "Error:The file 'creds.json' does not exist"
}
```

Comment: from what i can understand of your code, the `$File` variable in your Invoke-Command scriptblock will be written _where ever the current dir happens to be on the remote computer_. so ... are you certain that the file is _not_ being written? there is no real way to be sure where `"error_report.txt"` will be when that "path" gets used. [*grin*]

Comment: `error_report.txt` already exists in the same sir as my script

Comment: ah! i misread your post - i thot that the file was being written from INSIDE the `Invoke-Command` call, not _after_ it. please, ignore my error ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the way you are defining the condition on your if statement.
You use `-eq $false` however if you connections fails it does not set the vale of `command` to `$false` it will leave command as a null as it return no value (it errorred).
What you can try is either use the null operator (!) in your if statement so:

```
If (!$command){Do stuff}
```

Or you can give you invoke command an error variable and check if that has a value when run.

```
$command = Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server.$user_domain -FilePath 
     C:\SECnology\Data\Utilities\Updating.ps1 -ArgumentList 
     $user,$admin,$user_computer -Credential $credential -ErrorVariable TheError
     If ($TheError)
     {Do stuff}
```